# Why does the chlor alkali process work?

Tags: electrochemistry

Chlorine is a stronger oxidiser than oxygen, and sodium is a much stronger reducing agent than hydrogen. Therefore, in the chlor alkali process, when voltage is applied to the electrodes and the solution is one of brine, why don't we end up electrolysing the water instead? We should, in fact, start seeing chlorine gas formation only when the brine is extremely thick, almost like a semi solid.

Comment: Welcome to the chemistry site of the SE network.  

The site expects that you write explicit compact summary of your prior effort to answer the question, based on your knowledge and on searching for existing related  info or answers. It helps preventing  others to tell you what you already know or what you could easily find yourself. 

Effort not shown can be considered as effort not done and such a question may be  closed.  [How do I ask a good question?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Comparison of standard redox potentials compares redox systems at standard conditions. Consider how pH value changes the oxygen redox potential and high Cl- ions activity the chlorine redox potential. For sodium, consider hydrogen overpotential on mercury, high activity of Na+ ions and low activity of Na metal solution in the amalgam.